# Getting "view function did not return a valid response" error

Tags: python, api, flask

It is quite obvious to me that my `post` function is returning a value but I still get this error.

**Flask API Server:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# This script simulates the API

import sys
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api
from flask_restplus import Resource, reqparse, fields, inputs

app= Flask (__name__)
api = Api(
    app = app,
    version = "1.0",
    title = "Test",
    description = "Test")

# Get environment variables
try:
    api_port = os.environ.get ('API_PORT', 12345)
    api_host = os.environ.get ('API_HOST', '0.0.0.0')
except Exception as e:
    print ('Could not load all environment variables')
    print (e)
    sys.exit (1)

@app.route ("/register_user")
class RegisterUserClass (Resource):
    def __init__ (self):
        Resource.__init__ (self)

    def post (self):
        return True

app.run(host=api_host, port=api_port)
```

I am calling the endpoint like so

```
import http.client
    
api = http.client.HTTPConnection(
            host=api_host,
            port=api_port
        )

params = json.dumps({
        'email': 'john.smith@example.com',
        'username': 'john.smith',
        'password': 'password123'
    })

headers = {
    "Content-type" : "application/json",
    "Accept"       : "text/plain"
}    
try:
    settings.api.request(
        method  = 'POST',
        url     = '/register_user',
        body    = params,
        headers = settings.headers
    )

except Exception as error:
    pass
```

**Error:** I am getting the below error

```
$ ./api.sh 
 * Serving Flask app "api" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:12345/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2021-08-09 17:27:31,538] ERROR in app: Exception on /register_user [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2127, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a RegisterUserClass.
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2021 17:27:31] "POST /register_user HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[2021-08-09 17:27:31,540] ERROR in app: Exception on /register_user [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2127, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a RegisterUserClass.
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2021 17:27:31] "POST /register_user HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[2021-08-09 17:27:31,541] ERROR in app: Exception on /register_user [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2127, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a RegisterUserClass.
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2021 17:27:31] "POST /register_user HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: A view function can't return a boolean. Try `return str(True)`

Comment: @Kruspe I tried `return str (True)`, `return 'hello world'`, `return str('hello world')`. Still the same error